# Get all hyperlinks from page content in Sharepoint 2010 using powershell or object model?

Tags: powershell, hyperlink, pages, sitepages

We would like to get all hyperlinks within page content of each page(Sites Pages and Pages Library) in a site.

How to get all hyperlinks from page content in SharePoint 2010 using PowerShell or object model?

Is it possible? or we need to find all hyperlinks manually within content of the site. We would like to replace few hyperlinks with some different hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can't use PowerShell and Object Model to find links within `a content page`. it should be useful if it's Hyperlink columns within List.
So I suggest to using Jquery / Javascript At content Editor web part at your Page.

To get all Links and update its URL via Javascript

```
window.onload = function() {
       /* onload code */

 var anchors = document.getElementsByClassName("the class of your links");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = "http://www.example.com/?redirect=" + anchors[i].href
}
}
```

To update specific links using a Jquery

```
$("a[href^='http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/']")
   .each(function()
   { 
      this.href = this.href.replace("http://blog.devoworx.net");
   });
```

The first part selects only links where the href starts with `http://sharepoint.stackexchange`

See also more details at [How to change the href for a hyperlink using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179713/how-to-change-the-href-for-a-hyperlink-using-jquery)